# Unix return value "-bash"

Tags: bash, unix

I do not know what the return value means

```
grep abc Letters


echo $?
0
echo $0
```

gives "-bash"
what does "-bash" return value mean

Comment: should be migrated to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @umläute: I'm not sure it needs to be migrated. It's a question about programming, and Unix-specific programming questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. (It would also be a valid question for the Unix site.)

Comment: `$0` is not a return value at all; it's `argv[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

The question should be moved into https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

But anyway, `$0` is the value of the variable that holds the name of an application that's executing the command. It's like `argv[0]` in C.

Example:

```
cdshines@v3700:~|⇒  echo $0  # I'm in zsh now
/bin/zsh
cdshines@v3700:~|⇒  bash     # let's run bash:
cdshines@v3700:~$ echo $0
bash
cdshines@v3700:~$ sh         # we need to go deeper: 
$ echo $0
sh
$ zsh                        # deeper!
cdshines@v3700:~|⇒  echo $0
zsh
cdshines@v3700:~|⇒           # hit Ctrl-D (pop one level):
$ echo $0
sh
$                            # pop again:
cdshines@v3700:~$ echo $0
bash
cdshines@v3700:~$ exit       # again:
cdshines@v3700:~|⇒  echo $0
/bin/zsh                     # we're at the starting point now
```

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of `$0` is explained in the Bash manual ([here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html), near the bottom of the page):

> Expands to the name of the shell or shell script. This is set at shell
>   initialization. If Bash is invoked with a file of commands (see [Shell
>   Scripts](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Scripts.html#Shell-Scripts)), $0 is set to the name of that file. If Bash is started with
>   the -c option (see [Invoking Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html#Invoking-Bash)), then `$0` is set to the first
>   argument after the string to be executed, if one is present.
>   Otherwise, it is set to the filename used to invoke Bash, as given by
>   argument zero.

(Unfortunately, it's difficult to search for `$0` in the bash manual, since it's listed as just `0`.)

By convention, if the current `bash` process is a login shell, `$0` (`argv[0]` in C terms) is modified, either by `bash` itself or by the login process, adding a `-` character to the beginning.

On some systems, `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`. If so, and if `bash` is invoked via the `/bin/sh` symlink, then `$0` will be `sh` or `-sh`.

`$?`, also explained in the Bash manual, "Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline". More simply, it's the status of the most recently executed command (in your case, `grep abc Letters`), typically `0` if that command succeeded, or some non-zero value (often, but not always, `1`) if it failed.

Comment: Classically, it was the login process that set `argv[0]` to `-bash` to let the shell know it was a login shell — rather than the shell itself which usually can't meaningfully modify its argument list.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: A quick experiment on Linux shows that a C program that does `argv[0][0] = '-';` changes the program name that appears in the output of `ps`.

Comment: OK; I no longer have access to Solaris, HP-UX, AIX, but I'm pretty sure they don't, or didn't (within the last couple of years).  Mac OS X does accept the change (all arguments). I remember the difficulty because it was frustrating not being able to overwrite passwords passed on the command line on all Unix platforms.  There's a comment in some relevant code: `case 'p': /* Password - dubious security */ password = STRDUP(optarg); /* Overwrite password to reduce the chance of it being seen via ps, but it does not do anything useful on Solaris 7. */ memset(optarg, 'X', strlen(optarg)); break;`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I can confirm it doesn't work on Solaris 9. On Linux, I don't know whether the `'-'` is set by the shell, by `login`, or both. Perhaps I'll find the motivation to check. 8-)}

Answer (score 0):

Return status of the latest shell command is represented by `$?`:

```
date
echo $?
0
```

Here 0 means successful return from previously completed command(`date`) and any non-zero value means failure status.

When you access `$0` is is actually name of the executable in shell and in your case it is `-bash` since you're running it on the shell.